# When ViewDidLoad has an error, The PresentedViewController can't be dismissed and still become VisibleVC then How To Remove VisibleVC from Memory?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, modalviewcontroller

I have an issue. I want to remove presented view controller from memory. Let's say I have VC1 and I want to present VC2. The presented view controller (VC2) is on Visible View Controller. The presented view controller is failed to add on the view hierarchy because on ViewDidLoad has an error. So, the presented View Controller is stuck and whenever I go to another page the Visible View Controller is still appear , the instance is same and not removed. I want to remove the presented View Controller (VC2) from the memory So when user got the error then user still can navigate to another page without feeling stuck. Any advice is appreciated :)

So far, What I've tried..

#1.  I already try to dismissVC but the VC2 is still on the Visible View Controller

#2.  I already try to create new navigation controller and set the view controllers using old view controllers but still stuck and the other page become not responsive

My full code:

**VC1 :**

```
 public class ViewController1 : UIViewController
{
    public ViewController1() : base()
    {
    }

    private UIButton m_btnReference;

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

        m_btnReference = new UIButton();
        m_btnReference.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        m_btnReference.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
        m_btnReference.SetTitle("Clickkk!", UIControlState.Normal);
        m_btnReference.TouchUpInside += HandleButtonReferenceClicked;
        View.AddSubview(m_btnReference);
        View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(m_btnReference, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 10));
        View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(m_btnReference, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1, -10));
        View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(m_btnReference, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, 100));
        View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(m_btnReference, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 0));
    }

    private void HandleButtonReferenceClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var _getTopVC = GetTopVC(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController);

            ViewController2 _nextVC = new ViewController2();
            _nextVC.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom;
            _nextVC.ModalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true;


            if (_getTopVC.GetType().Equals(typeof(ViewController2)))
            {
                _getTopVC.DismissViewController(false, null);
            }

            _getTopVC.PresentViewController(_nextVC, true, null);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Error! because {ex}");

        };
    }

    private UIViewController GetTopVC(UIViewController aRootController)
    {
        UIViewController topController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
        while (topController.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            topController = topController.PresentedViewController;
        }
        return topController;
    }

    public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);
        Console.WriteLine("DidDisappear called!");
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
        Console.WriteLine("WillDisappear called!");
    }
}
```

**VC2:**

```
 public class ViewController2 : UIViewController
{
    public ViewController2() : base()
    {
    }

    private UITextView tvText;
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

        tvText.Text = "Tessssssss";
        tvText.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        tvText.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
        View.AddSubview(tvText);
        View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(tvText, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 0));
        View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(tvText, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1, 0));
        View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(tvText, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 0));
        View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(tvText, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));

    }

    public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);
        Console.WriteLine("DidDisappear called!");
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
        Console.WriteLine("WillDisappear called!");
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

**EDit #1:**

I added UIAlertVC when the catch exception is on progress. But, the dismiss progress still not working

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UIAlertController _alertController = UIAlertController.Create("Error", ex.ToString(), UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            _alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create(title: "Ok ",
                                                       style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                                                       handler: (obj) => { this.DismissViewController(true, null); }));

            GetTopVC(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController).PresentViewController(_alertController, true, null);

        };
```

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is not the right place for a check that prevents the view controller from loading; At this point the view is loaded and it is going to appear.  Either check and don't present the view controller if it shouldn't be shown, or if you have already presented the view controller then you should display some appropriate error message and provide some sort of control/button that the user can use to dismiss the view controller.  Having a view controller appear and then disappear is not a great user experience.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your time to give advice for me. I have tried to show UIAlertViewController on Catch Exception and the UIAlertViewController has an "OK Button" to let the user dismiss the view Controller but the VC2 still become VisibleViewController and seemed the dismiss process is not working. I have edit the question by adding the UIalertVC

Comment: Btw, I have a question how to check and don't present the view controller if it shouldn't be shown. How to know if the VC shouldn't be shown? Do you have any ideas to do that? Because how to know the error is from ViewDidLoad

Comment: I can't say explicitly how not to show the view controller; You haven't shown or explained what the error or condition is that leads you to not want to show the view controller, but the general approach is you do whatever task it is that vc2 does when it loads in vc1 and only show vc2 if necessary.    You have the right code to dismiss the modally presented vc2.